# Lock Method in C++ Application Multi-Thread

Tags: c++, sql, concurrency, synchronization

Is there any way to Lock a Method in a Multi-Thread Application ??

NB: to Access a MySQL DataBase

Best regards.

Comment: Google "Critical Section" c++ (actually, here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost scoped_lock is an easy and fool-proof way. Having the lock tied to an object like this automatically releases the lock when for any reason the scope is left. (return, exceptions, ...) Edit: Also note c++11: std::lock_guard and std::mutex as told by @Useless

```
class Foo 
{
 public:
 void bar() 
 {
   // Will grab the resource or wait until free
   ::boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex); 
   //Critical section

   // No need to unlock the lock will do that itself.
 }
private:
boost::mutex m_mutex;
```

}

this example was found here
http://developer-resource.blogspot.com/2009/01/boost-scoped-lock.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have C++11:

```
class Foo
{
    std::mutex bar_mutex;
public:
    void bar()
    {
        std::lock_guard guard(foo_mutex);

        // ... do your stuff here ...
    }
};
```

is equivalent to Johan's Boost version.

Note they both lock the method per instance - make the mutex `static` if you want all Foo instances to be prevented from calling `Foo::bar` at the same time.